# react-native-calendar-events fetch all events - problem fetching events on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to fetch all events via react-native-calendar-events package, which is working on iOS, but gives me an empty array on android all the time (sometimes there is just one entry in the array).

**The permission should be there I can get a list of calendars also**, there is no error thrown..nothing - the promise just always comes back with an empty array OR sometimes just one date from the calendar.

I already tried with and without calendar ids and different formats for the dates, still nothing seems to work.

```
const calendars = [];    
RNCalendarEvents.fetchAllEvents(today, fivetyFromNow, calendars)
            .then(result => {
                console.log('calendar events: ', result);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('calendar error: ', err);
            });
```

Date format that I feed is the following, that is achieved via moment.js:

> 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ'